# How add ASP.NET Core identity to existing Core mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have already started my dotnet core mvc project without identity on Mac with CLI and now I want to add this feature. The only option I have known till now is to create a new project by

```
dotnet new mvc --auth
```

Is there a better way to add identity to an existing project? I hope there is a 'dotnet new' command.

Comment: I look for an explanation why my question was so bad? It was a genuine doubt after all..!

Comment: I even found the way to the answer.  dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity would do the trick.

Comment: Starting with ASP.NET Core 2.1, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI is also being introduced.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add this NuGet package via CLI in VS Code:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

And if you want the standard UI pages you can install this package which contains everything embedded:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
```

Comment: There must be a typo here. Presumably the standard UI page package was intended to be "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI"?

Answer (score 24):

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization) you can scaffold identity into an existing MVC project with **aspnet-codegenerator**.

1) If you have not previously installed the ASP.NET Core scaffolder, install it now:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

2) Add a package reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design to the project (*.csproj) file. Run the following command in the project directory:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet restore
```

3) Run the following command to list the Identity scaffolder options:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

4) In the project folder, run the Identity scaffolder with the options you want. For example, to setup identity with the default UI and the minimum number of files, run the following command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI
```

5) The generated Identity database code requires Entity Framework Core Migrations. Create a migration and update the database. For example, run the following commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateIdentitySchema
dotnet ef database update
```

6) Call **UseAuthentication** after **UseStaticFiles**:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication(); // <-- add this line
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can manage this through the NuGet Package Manager:

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Console

`$` Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Answer (score 1):

I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization) MS tutorial but had some problems so I liste them here and solutions how I fixed them.

I had problems with connection string. This is how my connection string looked on the end in `appsettings.json` since my MS SQL server was working on specific port:

```
 "AuthDbContextConnection": "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,10008;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sqluser;Password=sqlpassword"
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is here instead of IP address.

I wasn't able to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore` so I went on packet page [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.entityframeworkcore/) and installed latest version for my project (.NET Core 3.x) which is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.10). So I've installed package with :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.10
```

After that I run

```
Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema -Context AuthDbContext
```

It didn't work without context parameter.
This created 2 migrations which I ran separately:

```
Update-Database 20201217102436_InitialCreate -Context AuthDbContext
```

and than

```
 Update-Database 20201218083037_CreateIdentitySchema -Context AuthDbContext
```

And that worked. Tables were created in MS SQL server successfully.